# How to fix an error when sending email in AsyncTask

Tags: android, email, android-asynctask

I am getting error while trying to send email. It worked well earlier, but I haven't been using it for a while. I don't know what causes of this. I've made lot of changes to this class, but I wasn't even touching this functionality, and I'm not sure if it's problem with code, which hasn't changed or, something changed with email functionality.
Here's the code:

```
class PhotoSend extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{

                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {


                            }

                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                                final String username = "user@gmail.com";
                                final String password = "password";

                                Properties props = new Properties();
                                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,

                                        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);

                                            }
                                        });

                                try {

                                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("user@gmail.com"));
                                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("anotheruser@gmail.com"));
                                    message.setSubject("Zamówiono części do zlecenia " + taskID);
                                    message.setText("Do następującego zamówienia " + taskID + " zostały zamówione części w liczbie " + partsCount + "\n\n" + "Opis:\n" + partPicturesDescription);
                                    Transport.send(message);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onInput: background");

                                } catch (MessagingException e) {

                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);

                                }
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wysłano", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onInput: postExecute");
                            }
                        }
```

and the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
                  Process: com.example.damianadamski.Service, PID: 6744
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
                      at com.example.damianadamski.service.Fragments.TaskFragment$5$1PhotoSend.doInBackground(TaskFragment.java:541)
                      at com.example.damianadamski.service.Fragments.TaskFragment$5$1PhotoSend.doInBackground(TaskFragment.java:498)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
                   Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
                      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
                      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
                      at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
                      at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
                      at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
                      at com.example.damianadamski.service.Fragments.TaskFragment$5$1PhotoSend.doInBackground(TaskFragment.java:536)
                      at com.example.damianadamski.service.Fragments.TaskFragment$5$1PhotoSend.doInBackground(TaskFragment.java:498) 
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: The issue is with your authentication. `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.`

Have you debugged your code properly ?

Comment: I did, and I've seen that error occurs at `send` method, but I have no idea why. I've checked first username and password, and there was no mistake, then I've checked  gmail option `allow less secure apps` but it was checked too

Comment: then there are 2 possibilities. either you are sending the wrong parameters or the service is not responding as the way it should.

Comment: I wasn't changing anything inside this class, so is there possibility service has changed?

Comment: yes absolutely the service can be changed. If you have access to your services too then I would suggest you to debug it thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I have done in my project like this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
final GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override public Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
        try {   
            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                "This is Body",   
                "user@gmail.com",   
                "user@yahoo.com");   
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
        } 
    }
}.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

login to your gmail and turn on the security it should work
Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps